# How to find out who has full mailbox access for a list of users in exchange 2010

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I need to figure out a way to see who has full access to a list of mailboxes in exchange 2010 PowerShell. I can use
Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxPermission | where {$*.user.tostring() -ne 
"NT AUTHORITY\SELF" -and $*.IsInherited -eq $false}
to see who has full access to every mailbox in my organization but was wondering if I can call a CSV or Text file to view permissions for those mailboxes listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can. You just call `Import-CSV` for CSV, or `Get-Content` for text files (one line = one name), then for the resultant array go `foreach { get_mailbox -identity $_.name | ...}`. An example:

```
<<text file follows>>
user1
user2
user3

<<script follows>>
get-content textfile.txt | foreach {
    get_mailbox -identity $_ | 
    get-mailboxpermission |
    where {$_.user.tostring() -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SELF" -and $.IsInherited -eq $false}
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you for the quick response.